# How to use IF on Excel to compare a Cell's value with a Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want set a date to a cell using a condition dependents of a cell's value. This is my work, but it doesn't works. Look at B7's formula and C7's value.
The date value seted is `00/01/00` but like condition should be `11/11/19`.

[image]

I tried use `$` too, but not works: `=IF(EXACT($C7;"Cartão de Crédito"); 11/11/19; 1/11/19)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the string:

11/11/19

with a `Date()` function call.

*(same for 1/11/19)*

**EDIT#1:**

for example:

```
=IF(EXACT(C7;"Cartão de Crédito");DATE(2019;11;11);DATE(2019;11;1))
```

or

```
=IF(EXACT(C7,"Cartão de Crédito"),DATE(2019,11,11),DATE(2019,11,1))
```

depending on your separator.

Comment: I tried `=IF(EXACT($C7;"Cartão de Crédito"); Date(); 1/11/19)` but generic erros occrus. Also `Date(19;11;11)` not works.

Comment: @Augusto  Use the equivalent to *DATE()* in the language of your Excel!

Comment: @Augusto  for example, in Portuguese you would use *DATA()*

Comment: I'm using in english. `=IF(EXACT(C7;"Cartão de Crédito"); DATE; 1/11/19)`. Keeps not working.

Comment: @Augusto  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the **VALUE** function but make sure to set the format of the cell to `date`:

```
=IF(EXACT(C7;"Cartão de Crédito");VALUE("11/11/19");VALUE("1/11/19"))
```

> The **VALUE** function will convert the text date into a numerical value representing the date in excel. As long as you set the format of the resulting cell to `date`, excel will display the date adequately for you.